# error with typescript compiler: property forEach doesnt exist in type sprite_loading

Tags: typescript

Hi I have interface in Typescript:

```
interface sprite_loading {
[index: number]: {
    URL: string,
    name: string
}}
```

I m creating an array inside the class:

```
public spriteLoading: sprite_loading;
```

But when I try forEach this array:

```
private preload() {
    var phaser = this;
    this.spriteLoading.forEach(function (element) { //here is the problem
        phaser.game.load.image(element.name, element.URL);
    });

}
```

I get this error, but code works.

```
engine.ts:57:28 - error TS2339: Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'sprite_loading'.
```

Why am I getting this error? Im sure that spriteLoading is an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are leaning on an array, you can get it's definition for free. Example:

```
interface sprite_loading extends Array<{ URL: string, name: string}> {
    [index: number]: {
        URL: string,
        name: string
    }
}

let example: sprite_loading = [
    { URL: 'foo', name: 'foo' },
    { URL: 'bar', name: 'bar' },
    { URL: 'baz', name: 'baz' }
];

example.forEach((val) => console.log(val.URL));
```

If you aren't being particularly funky with your `sprite_loading` interface, you might prefer to define the type of each entry as it is neater:

```
type Sprite = { URL: string, name: string, things: Thing[] };

let example: sprite_loading = [
    { URL: 'foo', name: 'foo' },
    { URL: 'bar', name: 'bar' },
    { URL: 'baz', name: 'baz' }
];
```

And this is a neat way to define further array members:

```
type Thing = { thingness: number };
type Sprite = { URL: string, name: string, things: Thing[] };

let example: Sprite[] = [
    { URL: 'foo', name: 'foo', things: [{ thingness: 5}, { thingness: 8}] },
    { URL: 'bar', name: 'bar', things: [] },
    { URL: 'baz', name: 'baz', things: [] }
];

example.forEach((val) => console.log(val.URL));
```

Comment: It's working, but I have no idea how. I will have to study typescript more.

Comment: It is probably very stupid question, but what should I do if I have 2 dimensional array?

Comment: That is lot better. Thank you